# À medida que o tempo passa e a progressbar cresce mudar o texto da label

Tags: c#, winforms

Antes de começar é apenas um jogo não um vírus.

O meu objectivo é quando quando a `progressbar` chegue a 1% ponha o texto como *downloading vírus* e quando chegue a 50% ponha o texto como *installing virus* mas em vez disso muda logo para *installing virus*.

Este é o código até agora:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
private void LetTheGameStart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
}

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (progressBar1.Value != 100)
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
            label2.Text = "Downloading Virus";
        }
    }
    if (progressBar1.Value != 50)
    {
        label2.Text = "installing Virus";
    }
}
```

Comment: Winforms, WPF ou WEB? Qual é o tipo de aplicação? Forneça mais informações a pergunta.

Comment: c# no visual studio

Comment: Sim, mas qual e o tipo de aplicação? Esta a usar Winforms ou WPF?

Comment: acho que é winforms. qual a diferença

Comment: já sei é winform

Comment: já está 100 mas continua com o mesmo problema e a progressbar não está a aumentar :(

Comment: @Pekira Tente assim: http://pastebin.com/ncZ780NN Talvez o erro esteja em `if (progressBar1.Value != 50)` deveria ser: `if (progressBar1.Value >= 50)`. Veja se funciona.

Comment: Quando o progressBar for `<=50` mostra `Downloading Virus` e quando for `<= 100` mostra `Installing Virus`, é isso?

Comment: Quando chega a 10 para e eu ja mudei para 100 o max

Comment: não é no inicio ou 1% aparece Installing Virus e quando chegar a 50% mostra Downloading Virus

Comment: Eu fiz aqui, mas so que de uma forma diferente da sua

Comment: como é que deu?

Comment: Vou publicar a resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando estiver usando o **ProgressBar** é muito útil usar o [BackgroundWorker](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjS6MG5g4_OAhVIPJAKHUxSCNkQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fpt-br%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNH-ZyE_JTmfY2o26Q9Li9HzNy7JMQ&sig2=pRe4Cl4Rw10nRtpdMc6vdQ) para aumentar a barrinha (propriedade `Value` do ProgressBar) e deixar a aplicação livre para fazer outras coisas.

## Implementando o BackgroundWorker

Primeiro vamos implementar o evento `DoWork` do `BackgroundWorker` para reportar o progresso:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{            
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) //loop para o progressbar
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
```

Em seguida deve implementar o evento `ProgressChanged` do `BackgroundWorker` para obter os valores que estão sendo passado para o ProgressBar e manipulados:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();

    if (progressBar1.Value >= 1 && progressBar1.Value <= 50)
    {
        label1.Text = "Installing Virus";                
    }
    else if (progressBar1.Value > 50 && progressBar1.Value <= 100)
    {
        label1.Text = "Downloading Virus";
    }
}
```

E por fim basta chamar o método `RunWorkerAsync()` do BackgroundWorker para ativa-lo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

PS: A propriedade `WorkerReportsProgress` do BackgroundWorker tem que ser definida para `true` para atualizar o progresso.

**Saida:**

Quando o valor esta abaixo de 50 exibe a mensagem `Installing Virus`:

[image: print 1]

Quando o valor esta acima de 50 exibe a mensagem `Downloading Virus`:

[image: print 2]

Você também pode utilizar o evento `RunWorkerCompleted` do BackgroundWorker para fazer algo quando o progresso for finalizado.

Fonte:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

Comment: podes me enviar o código é que não me está a dar o código não da erro mas não acontece nada

Comment: @Pekira aqui esta o [código](https://gist.github.com/drmcarvalho/21495978a186c00c44c7782397e88cd2).

Comment: Não sei o que se passa se eu te enviar os ficheiros do programa consegues me ajudar?

Comment: Se tiver mais duvidas, faça outras perguntas, vai perguntando nos pontos em que se tem duvida, desta forma fica melhor para ajudar.

Comment: Eu quando clico no botão não acontece nada continua sem dar

Comment: Tente executar o projeto completo, aqui esta os [arquivos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44ysxlt4lrz9ivv/ProgressBarExemplo.rar?dl=0).

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda :D